# C++ - How to delete a max element from queue

Tags: c++, arrays, queue, max

As you can see from the title I want to remove a element from a queue which is implemented using arrays.

So for example if I have:

```
array[]={1,5,4,3,2}
```

I want it to look like this

```
array[]={1,4,3,2}
```

I need to delete it from a queue but above is just a simple version of what I am trying to do. Here is the rest of the code that may help you, helping me.

```
class QueueArray: Queue <InfoTip> {

private:
 int capacity; // capacity
 int beginning; // index of the first element
 int end; // end of the array
 InfoTip *elements; // elements of queue

public:
 QueueArray(int capacity = 10) : capacity(capacity), // Konstruktor
 beginning(-1),end(-1), elements (new InfoTip[capacity]) {}
 ~QueueArray() { delete [] elements; }

template <typename InfoTip> // putting elements in a queue
void QueueArray<InfoTip>::putInArray(const InfoTip &x) {
     end = (end + 1) % capacity;
     elements[end] = x;
     if (beginning == -1)
         beginning= 0;
    }
```

And here is the function that I wrote for deleting max element from queue array

```
template <typename InfoTip>
void QueueArray<InfoTip>::deleteMax() {
    InfoTip max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        if(max < elements[i]) {
            max = elements[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` in your queue implementation instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`?

Comment: beginning not beggining

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah I got your point, but my question is not about queue implementation it is about deleting max element. But thanks anyway, if it will help me deleting my max element, I would gladly appreciate for you to elaborate.

Comment: @bloody Brother/sister that is not important. Don't comment just to get points hahah

Comment: My comment has everything to do with your question.  Instead of your code handling the memory management, use `std::vector`.  To remove the max element is one or two lines of code, not many lines full of `new[]` and `delete[]` calls.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks

Comment: @SamedŠkulj for comments there are no points. And my comment was genuinely honest - take care of the language, brother :)

Comment: `std::vector<InfoTip> elements;` -- would make things much easier.  No need for a destructor, and removal is very easy.

Comment: @bloody Yeah but my point is language is not important in my question, that is why I thought your answer was kinda unnecessary in this situation.

Comment: It seems you already have (mostly) working code to find the max. When finding the max, also track the index of that value, not just the actual maximum value. Then, write a function `void erase(size_t index)` which removes a single element from the array at the specified index. Note that if you use an existing data structure, this entire process is one line of code (because `erase` is already written); otherwise you'll need to implement `erase` from scratch yourself.

Comment: Note that comments may pertain to any aspect of presented code. This is what ***comments*** are for, as opposed to *an answer*. To help/suggest/advise/draw attention. Are English related comments common? No - I admit. However proper spelling contributes to smooth and uninterrupted readability of the code so this is even more than purely lingual remark if one didn't think so. As far as I have seen comments always carry a piece of good will. Thus don't misjudge their intentions or see pretending in them. Stackoverflow is a professional portal not a juvenile facebook chatroom. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use queue.

First you have to create a `temp` variable which will store all your `element` data.

```
for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
  if(max < elements[i]) {
    max = elements[i];
  }
  temp[i] = elements[i];
}
```

Then you have to create a `bool isTrue` variable becuase after you find the max element you have to skip an element

```
bool isTrue = false;
for(int i = 0; i < capacity-1; ++i) {
  if(temp[i] == elements[i]) {
    isTrue = true;
  }
  if(isTrue==true) {
    elements[i] = temp[i+1];
  }
  else {
    elements[i] = temp[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: The elephant in the room is that there is no adjustment as to the number of entries.  All this solution does is move everything down one entry.  The `vector` answer is much cleaner and actually will auto-adjust the size.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie he wanted to use `queue , not `vector`. I just answare to his question. I know that using vector in this case would be the best option, but he wanted to use queue.

Comment: I know he wanted to use queue.  The issue is that you failed to mention in your answer that the queue remains the same size, which is a highly important aspect to leave out of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a big favour and use STL containers and algorithms like so:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1 };
    v.erase(std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end()));
    for (auto x : v)
        std::cout << x << "  ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Prints:  1  2  3  4  4  3  2  1